# locate numpy indices based on closest value in 2d array with unmatch dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

**Made a mistake in the original version. The dimensions of arrays are unequal now. 
This is a stupid question but I can't find the right answer.
How do you index the closest number in a 2d numpy array? Let say we have

```
e = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5, 6]])
```

I want to locate the indices of values closest to 2, such that it return

```
array([1, 0])
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for ? an existing function that computes that ? Or you want to create such a function ? In this case where are you blocked ?

Comment: Did you mean 0, 1?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would use `np.argwhere(e == 2)`:

```
In [4]: e = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

In [6]: np.argwhere(e == 2)
Out[6]: array([[0, 1]])
```

In case you really need the output you specified, you have to add an extra `[0]`

```
In [7]: np.argwhere(e == 2)[0]
Out[7]: array([0, 1])
```

However, the input you provided is not a standard numeric array but an `object` array because `len(e[0]) != len(e[1])`:

```
In [1]: e = np.array([[1,2],[4,5,6]])

In [3]: e
Out[3]: array([list([1, 2]), list([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

This makes numpy much less useful and efficient. You would have to resort to something like:

```
In [26]: res = []
    ...: for i, f in enumerate(e):
    ...:     g = np.array(f)
    ...:     w = np.argwhere(g==2)
    ...:     if len(w):
    ...:         res += [(i, v) for v in w]
    ...: res = np.array(res)
```

Assuming this was a typo and if you are interested in the value closest to 2 even if 2 is not present, you would have to do something like:

```
In [35]: np.unravel_index((np.abs(e - 2.2)).argmin(), e.shape)
Out[35]: (0, 1)
```

Here I chose 2.2 as an example value.

Comment: Looks like the second half of the answer was invalidated by the latest update

Comment: Indeed. The last part is here to stay though ☺

Comment: Thank you!Sorry but I made a mistake. The reason I asked is because numpy doesn't allow me to subtract if the arrays in **e** are not in the same dimension. Such that

e = np.array([[2,3],[4,5,6]])
e - 0.05

 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

Comment: @KingvaderWong. Because you have a ragged list, which never really becomes an array...

Comment: @nicoco. Looks like your original version was actually what OP wanted. That's kind of surprising actually.

Comment: Doesn't really work with ragged list using argmin(). What would you suggest

Comment: @KingvaderWong A lot of numpy functionnalities are lost when you use a ` object` array, which is what happens in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by defining a function that works on a 1D array and applying it over the rows of the 2D array:

```
e = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

# function to find position of nearest value in 1D array
def find_nearest(a, val):
    return np.abs(a - val).argmin()

# apply it 
np.apply_along_axis(find_nearest, axis = 1, arr = e, val = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this is an old question, for "rectangular" arrays as in the other answers it's a one-liner

```
import numpy as np
e = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
val = 2.4

nearest = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(np.abs(e - val), axis=None), e.shape)

nearest
(0, 1)
```